# Why int(ls[:]) does not work in the function?

Tags: python

I worte two eqivalent(I thought) codes, while one works but the other report an error

```
a = 9
s = 0
ls = '1111'
for i in range(4):
    s = s + a* int (ls[0:i+1])
print(s)
```

This one return correct result.

```
def summ(a):
   s = 0
   ls = '1111'
   for i in range(4):
      s = s + a* int (ls[0:i+1])

print(summ(9))
```

This one reports an error

Comment: I tried your code, I didn't get an error. It printed `None`.

Comment: The `summ()` function doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to return s at the end of your function

Also your indentation is a little off.

```
def summ(a):
    s = 0
    ls = '1111'
    for i in range(4):
        s = s + a* int (ls[0:i+1])
    return s
```

Comment: Your indentation was off, but his was OK.

Comment: By OK I mean it was syntactically valid. It violated PEP8 since he used 3 spaces instead of 4.

Comment: thank you. this is helpful!